# How to listen for click events on the whole page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to listen to an event wherever I clicked on the whole page

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to the Scaffold:

```
body: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    onTap: () {
      // your code
    }
```

Comment: Good one, I used an overlay widget and wanted to dismiss if any area on the screen was clicked, this came in handy.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your MaterialApp widget with GestureDetector widget you can listen all kind of click. Example code is below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onDoubleTap: () {
        print('DobleTap');
      },
      onTap: () {
        print('ontap');
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[Text('Test')],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any  another way to handle this

Comment: What kind of way do you want? What is your aim to reach listening clicks? I am asking to understand

Comment: Actually I created an overlay I want to close it  onClick of outside

Comment: this does not work if i click on a button. The button or any click consuming widget will not trigger the top gestureDetector

Comment: @krishnaji Did you get any solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to wrap the screen with AbsorbPointer widget.

AbsordPointer as the documentation said, it is a widget that desable all the listners of the screen so if you have listView or another widget that we can click on it it will be desabled.

After that wrap The AbsorbPointer with GestureDetector and use the on Tap methode.

This is an example :

```
    import 'dart:typed_data';
    import 'dart:ui';

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
        runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
             home: HomePage(),
         );
      }
    }

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
        _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
       bool clicked = false;
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('object');
        },
        child: AbsorbPointer(
          child: Container(
            height: 500,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('$index');
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  color: index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```